# Moving file from one directory to another and delete from source directory using java

Tags: java, file, java-io

I am trying to move files from one directory to another delete that file from source directory after moving.

```
for (File file : files) {
    if (file != null) {
        boolean status = moveFile(file, filePath, name, docGroupId);
        if (status) {
            //some operations....
        }
    }
}
public static boolean moveFile(final File file, final String filePath, final String groupName, Integer docGroupId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String selectedDirectory = filePath + File.separator + groupName;
    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        if (!file.isDirectory()) {
            File dir = new File(selectedDirectory);
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                dir.mkdirs();
            }
            String newFilString = dir.getAbsolutePath() + 
                                  File.separator + file.getName();
            File newFile = new File(newFilString);
            in = new FileInputStream(file);
            out = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
            byte[] moveBuff = new byte[1024];
            int butesRead;
            while ((butesRead = in.read(moveBuff)) > 0) {
                out.write(moveBuff, 0, butesRead);
            }
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
        if(file.delete())
            return true;        
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The program works on `Linux-Ubuntu` and all files are moved to another directory and deleted from source directory, but in `Windows` system all files are moved but failed to delete one or two files from source directory. Please note that while debugging the program is working fine.

Comment: use can use apache io function org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.moveDirectory(srcDir, destDir);

Comment: any error? you should print the exception in catch block

Comment: I dont want to move all files from directory.only selected files

Comment: then use  moveFile Function or moveFileToDirectory(srcFile, destDir, createDestDir);

Comment: no exception or error occured...files remains in same directory..

Comment: I think problem is for file deletion delay taken by the system.anyone can tell how to handle delay problem

Comment: you are eating up the exception, nothing gets logged/printed in catch block. How are you sure that you don't get any error

Comment: I logged the exception and print the output in my running program and didn't get the exception

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Files.delete](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete%28java.nio.file.Path%29) instead of File.delete.  The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete%28%29) says:

> Note that the Files class defines the delete method to throw an IOException when a file cannot be deleted. This is useful for error reporting and to diagnose why a file cannot be deleted.

This should provide the information necessary to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, if problem comes with delete, possible explanations:

- you do file.delete() on every files and directories. How do you know the directory is empty ? If not, it will fail, then what happen to next instructions ?
- file deletion is OS-dependant. On Windows, you can have many security issues, depending on which user, which rights, which location. You should check with a file-delete-alone program;
- last: files can be locked by other programs (even explorer), it is also OS-dependant.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any of this if the source and target are in the same file system. Just use `File.renameTo()`.